# static member function make_shared of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, shared-ptr

Using *libc++* I find out `std::shared_ptr::make_shared()` static member function in public section. It is very handy when I have already defined type alias to `std::shared_ptr`'s specialization:

```
using T = int;
using P = std::shared_ptr< T >;
auto p = P::make_shared(123); // <=> std::make_shared< T >(123)
static_assert(std::is_same< decltype(p), P >::value);
```

I'm worry about standard compliance, because articles ([1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), [2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) from trusted source mentions nothing about static member function `make_shared` of `std::shared_ptr`.

Is it bad parctice to use the function currently? Why?

Comment: Isn't the fact that it doesn't exist in the standard a good enough reason?

Comment: You seem to already know that this function is non-standard. Isn't this just an opinion-based question?

Comment: I just checked the standard specification and it's not described there. This looks like implementation specific.
This does not work with VS2015 c++ standard library.

Comment: @Brian I can suppose, that my source is outdated or incomplete or inaccurate, because it is public wiki.

Comment: @T.C. Not for me, but maybe for others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using this static `make_shared` member function you depend on an implementation-specific extension of g++ / its standard library, as you already know. For the little gain you get from it, I would rather keep my code portable and use `std::make_shared`.

For the case you mentioned, i.e. constructing a  new object using copy or move constructor from an existing one, I can suggest an alternative (untested; for C++11-compatibility you would have to add a trailing return type):

```
template <typename T>
auto share_ptr_to_new(T&& v) {
    using T2 = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
    return std::make_shared<T2>(std::forward<T>(v));
}
```

In the example above, you could then just write `auto p = share_ptr_to_new(123)`.

Comment: Really close alternative for me is [overloading](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f87c5e9131d5eda7) of `make_shared` for `std::shared_ptr` itself somewhere in user namespace.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, there is

```
template<class T, class... Args> shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args);
```

as a non-member function.

You should be able to use `std::make_shared` instead of `std::shared_ptr::make_shared`.

Comment: It is copy-book maxim for me and many others, who deal with C++14's `<memory>`.

Comment: @Orient, I didn't understand that.

Comment: Copy-book maxim synonims: truism, common truth.